# Overflow hidden doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing text and image and text details within ul li and below is the html structure . I have applied overflow hidden to class .sbox but it doesn't seem to work and the text details doesn't appear to be hidden and overflown.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SAN6n/

### HTML

```
<div id="content" class="contentList">
  <ul id="slist" class="storyList">    
    <li>
     <div id="storyBox1" class="sbox"> 
        <div class="boxContent" >
            <span class="overlay"><h5>Picture1 </h5></span>
            <div class="txtOverlay"><h3>This is spring and weather looks good ...</h3</div>
            <span><img src="http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/38/picture11tp.jpg"/></span>
         </div>
      </div>
     </li>    
    </ul>
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
.storyList {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;   
}


.sbox {
float:left;
width:300px;
height:150px;
padding: 5px 7px 8px 5px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-right:40px;

background:white;
border:1px solid #DDD;

<!--border radius-->
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 3px;

overflow: hidden;

}

.boxContent {

width:100%;
height:100%;
border: 1px solid #777;
}

.storyList li {
list-style:none;
}

.overlay {

float:left;
opacity: .7;
background: #000;  
height: 40px;  
width: 300px; 
position: absolute;    
}


h5{
float:left;
margin-top:0px;
padding:0 0 0 5px;
font-family: Tahoma;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
font-size:30px;
color: white; 

}


.txtOverlay {
opacity: .7;
background: #000;  
height: 110px;  
width: 300px; 
position: absolute;        
margin-top:150px;
z-index:1;
font-weight:bold;
float:left;
font-family: OpenSansRegular;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
font-size:10px;
color: white;

}​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SAN6n/3/ <- fixed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SAN6n/2/)

I think this is what you need ?
Any time when you have `two` `div's` one `inside` the other the `first` div needs to be set to `relative` and the `other` div's need to be set to `absolute` position.

Answer (score 10):

It is because you are using position absolute.  You cannot use position absolute with overflow hidden, because position absolute moves the targeted element out of context with the document structure.

Answer (score 2):

Actually It is working, the padding you gave and the content it has, it making it useless of applying the `overflow:hidden;`

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/SAN6n/4/) to see my point, I have decrease the height, and the `overflow:hidden` is working.

Comment: Thank you all for your help .. i wanted the overlay div to slide up when there is mouse over the div .. but the overflow hidden is with respect to the main div and the slide up would happen from the border and not w.r.t to div which has class 'boxContent'

Answer (score 1):

when you give your element an absolute position - it can also be placed outside of the div's bounds - therefore - the overflow hidden should not be affecting it

Comment: thanks for reply yaron and austincheney.. so i removed position:absolute from txtOverlay class now the content is hidden but now the image is not seen..